# ASP.NET MVC after enabling bundle optimization for jQuery datatable some functions are not working, like fnStateSaveParams

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

In ASP.NET MVC after enabling bundle optimization for jQuery datatable, some functions are not working, like fnStateSaveParams.

After bundling functions or variables names are renaming like fnstatesave.
Before bundle optimization everything was working fine.
How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to explain your Question in more detail and share not working code too...

Comment: What's the behaviors of "not working", what's the error?

Comment: You probably now initializing with `DataTable()`, and before `dataTable()`